# Call MSSQL with Windows Auth from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Is it possible to call MSSQL from AWS Lambda when MSSQL is part of windows domain and only allows windows authentication? 
E.g. Is there any way to run Lambda function under AD user?
or use AD connector to associate AD user with IAM account and run Lambda under that account?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, we can use `pymssql` python module inside the lambda function to connect to mssql server and execute your commands. You need to zip the `pymssql` module as a lambda deployment package.
here is the example of command and connection:

```
import boto3
import pymssql
#setup connection
conn = pymssql.connect("serverurl", "username", "password", "dbname")
#setup cursor, so that you can use it to execute your commands
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE persons (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    salesrep VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)""")
# you must call commit() to persist your data if you don't set autocommit to True
conn.commit()
```

> But, to connect using Windows Authentication, here is some mods:
>   When connecting using Windows Authentication, this is how to combine the database’s hostname and instance name, and the Active Directory/Windows Domain name and the username.

```
conn = pymssql.connect(
    host=r'dbhostname\myinstance',
    user=r'companydomain\username',
    password=PASSWORD,
    database='DatabaseOfInterest'
)
```

Comment: It looks strange to me somewhat. The major difference in windows authentication is that connection is impersonated to current service account and there's no  need to pass username/password and store them anywhere.